# how to display dashboard at homepage in metabase?

Tags: metabase

I am new to the metabase. If anyone help me out that how to display dashboard at homepage while working on metabase.I tried but failed and search it on the google but did'nt find it anywhere.

Comment: by Homepage do you mean you want the dashboard to show up on the first page inside Metabase itself - or do you want to have it embedded on a webpage elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

To share the dashboard you can click on the sharing and embedding icon on the dashboard home page and enable sharing. It generates a public url which you can use to share instead of the default homepage